# Convert string to char for ascii

Tags: c++

I want to ask for word from the user and then convert the word from string to char using 'strcpy'. Then I want to determine the sum of the ascii codes for all of the letters in the word.

However, I am having difficulties. I don't understand exactly how I can do that. This is what I have been able to do so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;
    cout << "Enter word: ";
    getline(cin, word);
    /*
        char w[word];
        strcpy(w,word.c_str());
        int ('A');
        cout<<char(65); 
    */
    return 0;
}
```

The commented part is where I have been trying to do the converting. I copied the code from a worksheet. Even if it did work, I don't know how, and what it all means.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: You can't make a built-in array with a runtime-determined size.

Comment: This is my problem prompt:

Ask the user for a word (use a textbox).  Then determine the sum of the ascii codes for all of the letters in the word and state it in some label.  You will need a string.h include and you will need to convert the word (that you get from the user) from string to char using ‘strcpy’ function.

Comment: If someone's telling you to use `string.h` in a C++ program, you need to find a better class.

Comment: Also, the idea that you need `strcpy` is pure stupidity. There's simply no need to make a copy, and even if there was, you can copy strings directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char w[word];
strcpy(w, word.c_str());
```

`char w[word]` is incorrect. The square brackets is for the size, which must be a constant integral expression. `word` is of type `std::string`, so this makes neither logical nor practical sense. Maybe you meant it as:

```
char w = word;
```

But that still won't work because `word` is a string, not a character. The correct code in this case is:

```
char* w = new char[word.size() + 1];
```

That is, you allocate the memory for `w` using a `char*`. Then you use `word.size() + 1` to initialize heap-allocated memory amounting to those bytes. Don't forget for the obligatory `delete[]` when you're finished using `w`:

```
delete[] w;
```

However, note that using raw pointers and explicit `new` is not needed in this case. Your code can easily be cleaned up into the following:

```
#include <numeric>

int main ()
{
    std::string word;

    std::getline(std::cin, word);

    int sum = std::accumulate(word.begin(), word.end(), 0);                    /*
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    */

    std::cout << "The sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Fixed header (it's not in `<algorithm>`)

Comment: @0x499602D2: It's for numerical algorithms, also has `std::inner_product`, `adjacent_difference` and `partial_sum`. C++11 adds `iota`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `strcpy()`  (or use a `char *` at all, for that matter), but this'll do your counting using a `char` pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string word;

    std::cout << "Enter word: ";
    std::cin >> word;

    const char * cword = word.c_str();
    int ascii_total = 0;

    while ( *cword ) {
        ascii_total += *cword++;
    }

    std::cout << "Sum of ASCII values of characters is: ";
    std::cout << ascii_total << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$ ./asccount
Enter word: ABC
Sum of ASCII values of characters is: 198
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$
```

If you really do want to use `strcpy()`, I'll leave it as an exercise to you to modify the above code.

Here's a better way to do it, just using `std::string` (and C++11, *and* obviously presuming your system uses the ASCII character set in the first place):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string word;

    std::cout << "Enter word: ";
    std::cin >> word;

    int ascii_total = 0;
    for ( auto s : word ) {
        ascii_total += s;
    }

    std::cout << "Sum of ASCII values of characters is: ";
    std::cout << ascii_total << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

It would be EXTEREMELY helpful if you could do the modification of the code to strcpy(). I really do not know how to do it.

Thank you very much anyway.